# Lookup the subnets of many IPs in a fast way

Tags: php, subnet, cidr

I have a huge table which contains among other information and IP address column.

I want to do several calculations with this data but group it by the **subnets** to which the IPs belong. Currently I'm using whois to get an IPs subnet The problem with this approach is that it takes forever because I have several million different IPs in the table.
I already optimized the script by only looking up IPs which are not contained in any of the already known subnets, but it is still way to slow.

Is there a better, faster way to get the subnet than to use whois?

Comment: I guess no - and your second way isn't good enough since subnet can be changed (by leasing it to another operator, for example)

Comment: If you do not have the slash-notation of the IP addresses, the allocation that they are based on could change like the wind, depending on the IP allocation.

Comment: I guess you're only concerned with the granularity of assignments from ISPs to customers, not subnetting within organizations, right?

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right. What I'm trying to do is to find out which ISPs are generally used to abuse our services.

Comment: I think some IP geolocation services also include ISP information in their responses.

Comment: At the moment I'm directly using the "whois" command available on many linux systems. It automatically selects the correct whois server. But sadly it is not fast enough.

@Barmar I dont think that geolaction  services would be a lot faster.

Comment: Some geolocation services allow you to download the database and query it locally (we do this with MaxMind, but I don't think it has ISP information). Others may have an API that allows you to send a list of IPs instead of doing them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (kinda hacky) is to pull information from the [ARIN](http://arin.net) using a DOM script.

For example, if I go to http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/128.61.29.153, it will give me all the information I would want about the allocation to Georgia Tech.

Using the PHP [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), I can do this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/128.61.29.153');
# Insert DOM parsing here - it is not trivial but it is definitely possible.
```

This is not very fast, either, but it does provide another solution.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. Actually ARIN is a whois service, so that is the solution I've already tried. Additonally ARIN does not work internationally.

Comment: Sorry about that. Wasn't sure which way you were doing it.